# How can I style a DataGridCell's content based on binding without naming that binding

Tags: wpf, binding, styles, converters

I would like to create a style that makes my cell's content green if positive, red if negative or black if 0.

I know about converters and bindings, but is it possible to do this without naming the field the specific column is bound to (eg. I was to base on whatever is the cell's value)?

```
            <Style x:Key="GreenIfPositive" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource greaterThanZeroDecimalConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger BBinding="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource greaterThanZeroDecimalConverter}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

So that I could use it on columns without re-iterating that style just so I can select the property I'm basing this on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution for `DataGridTextColumn`s. DataGridTextColumn creates TextBlock element to display cell value. TextBlock has string `Text` property. Those TextBlocks can be accessed via DataGridCell `Content` property, so resulting binding path is "Content.Text"

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                 Path=Content.Text, Mode=OneWay,
                 Converter={StaticResource greaterThanZeroDecimalConverter}}" 
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                 Path=Content.Text, Mode=OneWay,
                 Converter={StaticResource greaterThanZeroDecimalConverter}}" 
                 Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                 Path=Content.Text, Mode=OneWay}" 
                 Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

note `{RelativeSource Self}`.

I also had to change `Convert` method because Text is a string property and incoming value is string.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    double d;
    if (value != null && value is string && double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d))
    {
        return d > 0;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea!

I only had to revert Path and RelativeSource. This could be a Visual Studio version-specific problem but, as is, your solution had it complaining about nested types not being supported.

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource greaterThanZeroDecimalConverter}}" Value="True">`

Worked wonders. Just edit that and I'll accept your answer ;)

Comment: @BenoitDufresne, fixed per request