# Use Converter for Cells in DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid, code-behind

Is there a way to attach a converter to every cell in a GridView to allow to change the color depending the text content?

Datagrid sample with color. How it should looks like.

[image: Datagrid sample with color]

XAML

```
  [![<DataGrid x:Name="dgvData" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  />][1]][1]
```

Code Behind

```
    Dim tableView As DataView = New DataView(DataTable)
    Me.dgvData.ItemsSource = tableView
```

What I did so far is using the style and attaching the Converter.
But in style, I have no access to the data. And in data, in case it is auto generated, I have no incluence to the cell background color.

Comment: check [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701332). create a converter, create a DataGridCell style which changes color based on value using converter, assign that style to DataGrid.CellStyle property

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by binding to Content.Text property.

Sample converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var x = value;
        return x.ToString() == "1" ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Sample XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="Conv"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgvData" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Content.Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Conv}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>            
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```